# SurfDescriptorExtractor doesn't create the descriptor matrix

Tags: opencv, surf, feature-descriptor

I have a problem with SurfDescriptorExtractor in OpenCV. It doesn't create a matrix at all!

The thing is that I'm imposing the key points, and right now, to debug, I only use 4-5 of them. I create the key points with cv::Keypoint, and use the default constructor. I set the coordinate of the point and the octave to 3. The rest, I'm not touching it!

Here's a piece of code of what I'm doing:

```
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
cv::detail::ImageFeatures &cdif = features[i];
Mat gray_image = imread(images[i], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
extractor.compute(gray_image, cdif.keypoints, cdif.descriptors);
```

And this is how I create my key points, this is what is in the loop:

```
  KeyPoint kp;
  kp.octave = 3;
  kp.pt.x = jpic.x;
  kp.pt.y = jpic.y;
  features[i].keypoints.push_back(kp);
```

So, is there a way to force the extractor to write something in the descriptor ?

Comment: Is there any detail I can add to help you with that question ?

Comment: I tried adding random point to the keypoint to have a larger set, but it doesn't change anything! I think it's the only thing that needs to work for my project to be finished! Please help!